# React Workbox PWA App on Subdirectory with react router custom basename

Tags: reactjs, react-router, workbox

I'm working on react Project which uses `react-router` as its routing Library.
since I want to run that project on a subdirectory of the website, I set the `react-router` basename attribute to 'my' in my app.js file.

**App.js**

```
<BrowserRouter basename={'/my'}>
```

and also  I set the `homepage` property in the `package.json` file

**package.json**

```
"homepage": "/my",
```

the app works charming until I decided to make the app `PWA` using `workBox`.

**craco.config.js** Or **Webpack.config.js**

```
 plugins: [
          new InjectManifest({
            swSrc: "./src/src-sw.js",
            swDest: "sw.js",
          }),
        ],
```

I tried to build  and check if it's working, but it simply doesn't show me the any registered workers On the **Application tab** in the **Chrome Developer Console**
but as soon as  I remove the `basename` attribute and `homepage` property, everything works, and the `service worker`  and `manifest.json` files appear Application Tab

[Application Tab on chrome Developer Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vUen.jpg)

[Console Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEcLQ.jpg)

[Manifest section On Application tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKnwv.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling with the Problem and reading so many articles and issues on Gits and etc, I found that the service worker has the scope and the default scope is `/` or `root` of your `host`. if you want to extend the scope and run service worker from the subdirectory you need to set  `Service-Worker-Allowed` header.

References:

> [Service Workers Documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers)

> [Two HTTP headers related to Service Workers you never may have heard of- by Thomas Steiner](https://medium.com/dev-channel/two-http-headers-related-to-service-workers-you-never-may-have-heard-of-c8862f76cc60)

> [How exactly add "Service-Worker-Allowed" to register service worker scope in upper folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49084718/how-exactly-add-service-worker-allowed-to-register-service-worker-scope-in-upp/49098917/)

Comment: Please add a bit of supporting context.

Comment: I've put some links in the Reference section